# Unable to start tomcat in eclipse after setting up my maven project in mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, maven, tomcat, catalina

I am unable to start my Tomcat server in eclipse to run my newly set up maven project in mac os. The same was working fine in windows os. I am using Tomcat 8.5. I have installed JDK, Maven and also set their environment and path variables. I have also updated all the maven dependencies. I have also added proper VM Arguments to Tomcat. However everytime i startup, whatever i do, i get the below attached error. Can someone please help me out. Please let me know if you need more inputs from me.
[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Can you copy and paste that view's contents *as text*? It looks incomplete at the least.

Comment: @nitind i am not getting which view's content you were interested about. But here's the code from context.xml in Web/Meta-INF.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" docBase="" path="" reloadable="false" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:cougar">
    <Loader loaderClass="com.greytip.cougar.tomcat.CougarClassLoader"/>
</Context>`

Comment: I was referring to the Console View shown in the image.